# Solve $y+3=3\sqrt{y+7}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $y+3=3\sqrt{y+7}$

$\Rightarrow (y+3)^2=9(y+7)$

$\Rightarrow y^2+6y+9=9y+63$

$\Rightarrow y^2-3y-54=0$

$\Rightarrow (y-9)(y+6)=0$

$y=9, -6$

But plugging $y=-6$ into $y+3=3\sqrt{y+7}$ yields $-3=3$.

I know the convention is $\sqrt{y}$ is equal to a positive number, but in this case $\sqrt{y+7}=\sqrt{-6+7} = \sqrt{1} = +1$, so why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because a second look to equation show that LHS must be $+$  so $$y+3=3\sqrt{y+7} \ge 0\\\text{This mean}\\y+3\ge 0\\$$so $y=-6 \ $doesn't work here

Comment: How can you tell it must be positive?

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson: Because $$\sqrt{y+7} \ge 0\\3\sqrt{y+7} \ge 3*0\\y+3=3\sqrt{y+7} \ge 0$$ so $$y+3\ge 0 \\y\ge -3$$

Answer (score 1):

When you square an equation you allow for negative solutions too for instance

$$x-1=1$$

By squaring on both sides

$$
x^2-2x=0
$$

This comes from the fact that an equation and an equation squared on both sides are not equivalent

When you apply square root it introduces mod and hence the two answers

$$x^2-2x=0\\
(x-1)^2=1\\
|x-1|=1$$

Which is not the same as $x-1=1$

Side note this is the reason why quadratics generally have 2 solutions

Comment: Can you explain to me what mod is?

Comment: The modulus function on real numbers just gives the positive value of a number $|3|=3\quad$$|-3|=3$